# Browser uses samesite=lax even if samesite=none is specified

Tags: iframe, setcookie, response-headers, samesite, third-party-cookies

I am trying to embed my angular application to another site through iframe. In my angular application I am setting cookies and so when I try to embed the angular application to my other site, the Devtools shows an issue which tells me, that samesite=none wasn't set so the default samesite=lax is being used, which prevents the angular application to set cookies.

Afterwards I tried to set in the response Header the entry "set-cookie: samesite=none; secure", but it didn't work. As you can see on the screenshot below, the browser still uses "same-site=lax".

This issue happens on Chrome and Edge(Chromium) but not in Firefox.

**Questions:**

- I want to know if I am using the same-site setting incorrectly?
- Why does the browser show me this message although I use "samesite=none;secure"?

**Screenshot**:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

You're misunderstanding `Set-Cookie`'s syntax, and you've mistakenly omitted the cookie's name and value. Check out [the MDN page on the topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie):

> A cookie definition begins with a name-value pair.

Accordingly, when the browser receives a response with the following header,

```
set-cookie: samesite=none; secure
```

it creates (or updates) a `Secure` cookie whose *name* is `samesite` and whose *value* is `none`. Because the `SameSite` *attribute* isn't specified and because [Chromium now defaults to `Lax` for the `SameSite` attribute](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592), the resulting cookie is effectively marked `SameSite=Lax` by your browser.

### Solution

To fix this, you must choose a name and a value for your cookie and you must specify the cookie's name and value before any other cookie attributes:

```
Set-Cookie: <cookie-name>=<cookie-value>; SameSite=None; Secure
```